# Rails Merge Form Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails 3.2.18 app in which I'm doing a simple create/update action on a model.

There's a field called sms which I used ActionMailer to send a message to a person's phone in the form of 2812222222@vtext.com.  Currently I manually type this in which is fine, but I want other's to be able to enter a phone number, select a carrier and have these two items merge into the proper format in the sms field again being 2812222222@vtext.com.  Makes it a lot more user-friendly than having to know the full sms-to-email address by heart.

I assume I can do most of this via JS/JQuery, but I'm not sure on how to get started.

I'd like them to be able to enter the phone number in a 281-555-4444 format and have the carrier select as a drop-down of Tmobile, Verizon, etc and substitute @tmomail.net, @vtext.com, etc, strip (regex) the phone number and merge it with the carrier (@vtext.com) into the sms field.

If anyone can point me in the right direct, it would be appreciated.

Update:

I figured I could use a helper method to define the carriers:

```
def phone_carriers
{
  "All Tell" => "@message.alltel.com",
  "AT&T" => "@txt.att.net",
  "Boost" => "@myboostmobile.com",
  "Cellular South" => "@csouth1.com",
  "Centennial Wireless" => "@cwemail.com",
  "Cincinnati Bell" => "@gocbw.com",
  "Cricket Wireless" => "@sms.mycricket.com",
  "Metro PCS" => "@mymetropcs.com",
  "Powertel" => "@ptel.net",
  "Qwest" => "@qwestmp.com",
  "Rogers" => "@pcs.rogers.com",
  "Sprint" => "@messaging.sprintpcs.com",
  "Suncom" => "@tms.suncom.com",
  "T-Mobile" => "@tmomail.net",
  "Telus" => "@msg.telus.com",
  "U.S. Cellular" => "@email.uscc.net",
  "Verizon" => "@vtext.com",
  "Virgin Mobile USA" => "@vmobl.com"
}
```

end

Add attr_accessor :carrier to the Person model

Then in the form do something like this:

```
<%= f.input :phone, placeholder: "555-555-5555", required: true, input_html: {required: true} %>

<%= f.select :carrier, phone_carriers.map{ |k, v| [k, v] }, {include_blank: true}, {placeholder: "Select your phone carrier", class: "select2"} %>
```

But I'm still having problems figuring out how to strip the phone number to 5555555555 and merging the :phone field with the :carrier object into the :sms field automatically (preferably client side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a lot of research and breaking things, I've come up with the following to make this work.  The model and form only show what changes I've made, not the full form or model.

Form

```
<%= f.label 'Cell_Phone'%>
<%= f.text_field :phone, placeholder: "xxx-xxx-xxxx", required: true %>
<%= f.label :carrier, "SMS Notifications", class: "control-label" %>
<%= f.select :carrier, phone_carriers.map{ |k, v| [k, v] }, {include_blank: true}, {placeholder: "Select your phone carrier", class: "select2"} %>
<%= f.hidden_field :sms %>
```

Model

```
attr_accessible :carrier
attr_accessor :carrier
```

CoffeeScript

```
$ ->
  $("#person_carrier").on "change", update_sms_address
  $("#person_phone").on "keyup", update_sms_address
  update_sms_address

update_sms_address = ->
    digits  = $("#person_phone").val().match(/\d+/g)
    phone   = digits.join("") if digits
    carrier = $("#person_carrier").val()

    if phone? && phone.length == 10 && carrier
      sms = phone + carrier
      $("#person_sms").val(sms)
      $("#person-sms-number").html(sms)
    else if !carrier
      $("#person_sms").val("")
      $("#person-sms-number").html("Choose a carrier to receive SMS notifications")
    else
      $("#person_sms").val("")
      $("#person-sms-number").html("Invalid phone number")
```

This seems to work when entering a phone number in the format of 281-444-4444 as it strips the number down and joins it with the value from the carrier array and sets the hidden :sms field appropriately.

The only problem I have now is since I'm using a virtual attribute for the carrier, if I go to edit the person again it doesn't retain the carrier select and leaves it blank.  If I submit the form without changing any info it will retain the :sms field, but it could be confusing since the :carrier is not an actual field that is remembered by the database but instead a virtual attribute.

Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: Why isn't carrier a persisted field?  If you need to remember it for next time, make a database column for it.

Comment: Also, the `carrier` field is blank because person.carrier is blank--it returns the default value of @carrier.  If you define it, the field will show whatever the method returns: `def carrier; sms.split('@')[1]; end`.  You may even want to do this in an after_find block so it only has to be calculated once: `after_find do; @carrier = sms.split('@')[1]; end`

Answer (score 0):

If you used the standard javascript string library, wouldn't something like

```
function prepare(str){
  str2 = str.replace("(","").replace(")","").replace("-","")
  carrier = getCarrier //assuming this implemented by you somewhere 
  return (st2.concat(carrier))
}
```

Comment: I suppose it could work.  But I really need to figure out how to not only strip the number of any formatting but also concatenate it with a carrier field and populate the sms field automatically via JS/Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by creating a carriers table:

```
rails generate model Carrier name:string email_domain:string
```

And referencing it in the Person model by adding the following to your migration:

```
change_table :people do |t|
  t.references :carrier
end
add_index :people, :carrier_id
```

And the following to your People model:

```
belongs_to :carrier
validates_presence_of :carrier

def sms
  carrier ? "#{phone}@#{carrier.email_domain}"
end
def phone_with_dashes
  "#{phone[0..2]}-#{phone[3..5]}-#{phone[6..9]}"
end
def phone_with_dashes=(_phone_with_dashes)
  self.phone = _phone_with_dashes.gsub(/-/ ,'')
end
```

Now, your view (I'll leave the formatting to you):

```
Phone: <%= f.phone_field :phone_with_dashes %>
Carrier: <%= f.collection_select :carrier_id, Carrier.all, :id, :name %>
<div id='person-sms-number'>
  <%= f.object.sms %>
</div>
```

Lastly, the Coffeescript: The only thing that has to change here is you no longer need the '#person_sms' input since you are no longer persisting the value directly--you are generating it dynamically from other fields.